# how to use fzf on Mac Terminal with bash

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I found a utility called fzf https://github.com/junegunn/fzf which is a fuzzy-finder for your shell.

Two questions:

1) After I run `fzf` and run a file, I press `Enter` and then the file I found is output in Terminal. Instead of `Enter`, what key should I press to copy that file path to my pastebin?

2) Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this:
`cat <pattern><hotkey>`
where I type part of the name of a file and then press a hotkey to start an fzf search for that pattern. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you write "to my pastebin?"  You mean to your clipboard

Comment: I meant to say "pasteboard" as described in `man pbpaste`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest that you read through the [README page](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf). You need a basic level of understanding of shell scripting in order to fully utilize fzf.

fzf is a Unix filter just like grep or sed, and all it does is to print the selected items. What to do with the output is completely up to you.

---

> 1) After I run fzf and run a file, I press Enter and then the file I found is output in Terminal. Instead of Enter, what key should I press to copy that file path to my pastebin?

You can use `pbcopy` command to store the result in clipboard like so:

```
fzf | pbcopy
```

More conventional way to use fzf is to use it with command substitution:

```
cat $(fzf)
```

Or to use the `CTRL-T` key binding that pastes the names of the selected files onto the command line:

```
cat <CTRL-T>
```

---

> 2) Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this: cat  where I type part of the name of a file and then press a hotkey to start an fzf search for that pattern. Is there a way to do this?

fzf is shipped with fuzzy-completion for bash. See [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#auto-completion) for more details. To invoke auto-completion, append two asterisks to the pattern and hit the tab key as follows:

```
cat pat**<Tab>
```

If you don't use bash, the closest you can do is to use CTRL-T keybinding mentioned above.

See: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#key-bindings-for-command-line

Comment: Ah, I found out my problem. I installed fzf via homebrew (`brew install fzf`), and the `CTRL-T` and `pat**<Tab>` shortcuts didn't work. I now installed fzf directly from the GitHub repo, and everything works now.

Comment: `brew install fzf` will only install fzf executable. In order to install extra features, you have to run the attached `install` script after the installation. See `brew info fzf` for more info.

Comment: @JunegunnChoi yeah that's mentioned https://www.aheil.de/2019/04/07/fzf-command-line-fuzzy-finder-on-macos-x/

Answer (score 2):

I tried installing fzf via homebrew and my CTRL-T and pat** shortcuts also did not work. I found that fzf added some commands to my .bashrc, but my .bashrc doesn't get called.

```
[ -f ~/.fzf.bash ] && source ~/.fzf.bash
```

Putting that same source statement from .bashrc into .bash_aliases did the trick for me.

Comment: `.bash_profile` for me..  'cos apparently osx doesn't use .bashrc it uses .bash_profile